# How to implement a protocol stack in an RF module?

Tags: networking, protocols, pic

I am doing a project using RF communication between pic microcontrollers. I would like to implement a protocol for better performance. How to implement the protocol in the RF module?

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of work from scratch. Start by reading about the [OSI 7 layer protocol model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) and then how other protocols work. Or choose an existing protocol such as [Microchip's MiWi](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2113&param=en520414). You'll find that the RF chip you are using may help with some aspects of the protocol. Don't forget to read up on the regulatory requirements for your geographic area ([ETSI](http://www.etsi.org/website/homepage.aspx) in Europe, FCC in US etc). They can dicate more than just transmit power and frequency, they can include message timings and duty cycle which will impact your software and protocol design.